# resizing the Picturebox as in Zooming, without the lag it causes

Tags: c#, zooming, picturebox, lag

I've made a sort of paint program that can make lines and icons and has a image on the back were will be painted on. this picture i want to scale by using the scroll wheel.

the problem i find is when i resize it, witch works i find that while on 100% of size there is no lag at all while moving icons around , but zoomed in like 200% for example it is laggy.

What would be a smart and proper way to fix this ?

Code :

```
@ Scroll wheel
previousWidth = previousWidth * 1.25;
previousHeight = previousHeight * 1.25;
pictureBox1.Width = (int)previousWidth;
pictureBox1.Height = (int)previousHeight;
// the previous height is to avoid losing the 0.xxxx and so rescaling will
// not eventually end up in a 1 by 1 pixel image or too large.

array.zoomOut(); //makes the lines zoom properly with the picture
icon.zoomOut(); // makes the icons zoom properly with the picture

pictureBox1.Refresh();


// @ opening the file // 
file = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);

pictureBox1.Image = file;
pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(file.Width, file.Height);
bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);

pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height));

pictureLoaded = true;
previousWidth = pictureBox1.Width;
previousHeight = pictureBox1.Height;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing WinForms? Do you mean flickering when you say "laggy".

Try to set the Property `DoubleBuffered` of the Form to True. Like mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Hey ec8or,  no i mean slow,  and i think doublebuffered is automaticly to true in pictureboxes, not in panels though. thanks for you suggestion still.